# MySQL 5.6 vs 5.7 + PHP autocommit(false)

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I recently upgraded from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7 and for some reason, using $db->autocommit(FALSE); in 5.7 just doesn't insert into db, but when I switch back to 5.6: all good.  Any ideas?

```
$db->autocommit(FALSE);

$query = "INSERT INTO test (one, two) VALUES (?, ?) ";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('is', $one, $two);
        $statement->execute();

$query = "INSERT INTO test2 (one2, two2) VALUES (?, ?) ";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('is', $one2, $two2);
        $statement->execute();

$db->commit();
```

connection string

ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

```
$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options ($db, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

$db->ssl_set('/tmp/client-key.pem', '/tmp/client-cert.pem', '/tmp/server-ca.pem', NULL, NULL);

$link = mysqli_real_connect ($db, '111.111.111.111', 'test', 'test', 'test', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
//$db->set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: `Call to a member function autocommit` means your `$db` variable is boolean (so you probably didn't manage to create a connection to the database).

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the db error thinking that was the issue.   Now no error, just doesn't insert.

Comment: When you say "no error" - how did you manage to fix the error? What do you get when you try to `var_dump($db);`?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function autocommit() on boolean in..

Comment: So you didn't fix the problem

Comment: haha, sorry.  I really appreciate your help.  So what's weird, same connection string, on a page that I don't use autocommit(false), it posts fine.    And of course both pages work fine in 5.6.  I'll keep debugging..

Comment: This is not related to the autocommit

Comment: I added my connection string... You're probably right, I just don't have any ideas.

Comment: Try to change your code to `mysqli_real_connect( ... ) or die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());`